# Rails 3 only need to edit one field from a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Order has_many :items and Accepts Nested Attributes for.

Want to loop through the items in the Order form, but only need the item.qty field to be editable.  Would like to display the other fields as normal <%= item.name %>, etc.

I know that I can use readonly and disable or even clean it up with css, but wondering if there is a better way.

order form looks like this.

```
<%= form_for [current_company, @order] do |f| %>
 ...
  <%= f.fields_for :items do |item| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'item', :locals => { :item => item } %>
  <% end %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

item partial looks like this.

```
<tr class="item">
  <td><%= item.text_field :name %></td>
  <td><%= item.text_field :short_description %></td>
  <td><%= item.text_field :price %></td>
  <td><%= item.text_field :qty %></td>
  <td> <%= item.text_field :full_price %> </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= item.object.name %>
<%= item.object.description %>
```

etc